# Fast, independent random draws / sample from a list in python - fixed probability, not total number

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

I'd like to draw a sample of items from a list, but I want to set the probability each item is included, *not* the total number of items to draw (so random.sample() does not work). I get the effect I want with the following code (where p is probability of inclusion, and items is the list of things):

```
[item for item in items if random.random() < p]
```

But it is very slow. Any suggestions for speeding it up?

The list is up to 10 million items long and single typed (all integers), so maybe there's a numpy / pandas solution to this?

Thanks!

Nick

Comment: if you want each item based on individual probability  I cannot see how you would do much better than you are now, what do you want to do with the values?

Comment: Running epidemiology model. Calling to C function to move selected individuals from "susceptible" to "infected" sets. Have ~10 million observations, and this is by far slowest part of code, so was hoping for some way to speed up, like a compiled function for sampling that selects with probabilities rather than drawing a fixed number of items.

Comment: You could make it a generator expression  and iterate over if you just want to use each item

Comment: I see how that might add speed down the line (since i'd only read through the list once), but it doesn't seem to solve the challenge of sampling quickly, which I think is the problem. 30% of my runtime is repeated calls to random.random().

Comment: (But i'll try it now to be sure! :))

Comment: unfortunately if you want a unique random value for each item there have to be len(items) calls. At least a generator expression will avoid having to create  it all in memory. See how you go anyway

Comment: also  `r = random.random` and using `r()` in the loop may help 
`(item for item in items if r() < p)`, knocks about 20/25 percent off for me

Comment: yup -- iterating saves me 30% time, and r() knocks off a bunch too. Great tricks Padraic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of items in your resulting sample (`n` attempts each independently with probability `p`) has a binomial distribution and thus can rapidly be randomly generated e.g with `numpy`:

```
sample_size = numpy.random.binomial(len(population). p)
```

Now, `the_sample = random.sample(population, sample_size)` gives you exactly what you desire -- the equivalent of randomly, independently picking each item in the population with the same probability `p`.

This is based on your example code which you say is too slow but also say it's otherwise OK -- i.e, the same `p` for every item in the population.  If each item has a totally different `p`, this can't work (if there are a few different values of `p` it can work by stratified sampling -- segment the population into uniform ones, each sub-population with a single value of `p`, and get samples from each of them independently, then union them).

Comment: Brilliant! Oh statistics, how useful you are.